# SQLServer foreign key wont let me add constraint with cascade (on delete or update)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, constraints

I have a simple datamodel in my database with three tables:

- State
- Ticket
- SubTicket

One ticket can have zero to multiple subtickets.
Every ticket and every tubticket can have one state.

So my database looks like this:

[image: my example Database]

between: xTicket and xState i have the constraint:

`on update cascade` / `on delete no action` (updating the `StateID` in `xTicket` when changed, probihit deleting the entry in `xTicket`)

between: xSubTicket and xTicket I have the constraint:

`on update cascade` / `on delete cascade` (updating the `TicketID` in `xSubTicket` and deleting an entry when an entry in `xTicket` is deleted)

but when I want to the same constraint as for `xTicket` and `xState` for:

`on update cascade` / `on delete no action` I get the following message:

***Foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths***

the foreign key will only let me set the constraint `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to either between xTicket and xState or between xSubTicket and xState.

so far I have found other questions about the same issue, where I got to know: either change the database design properly or the use of `INSTEAD OF Triggers`. - I actually want to know why this design is not acceptable, what am I doing wrong? How do I do it correctly?

thanks for any suggestion in advance

Answer (score 1):

> I actually want to know why this design is not acceptable,

Why do you think ti is not acceptable? This is merely a limitation of SQL Server. An inconvenient one.

You are free to code around it and use triggers to do the cascading operations.

I would ague your design is broken because hard deleting states should never happen and you try to do the database do cleanup that may well be more complex. I would go for a soft delete (marking a state as not available for new objects) so the cascade operations make no sense there. But that is another discussion and outside of the topic of your question.

Comment: I thought a simple example as this might contain an error I am blind of. Thats why I think so. - A subticket should be removed when its owner is gone, correct. But for states I want the flexibility to change the keys: e.g. my keys are: 1: Unread 2: Accepted 3: Solved. I want to add a new state now: Read at the correct position which is 2. therefore i want 3 to become 4, 2 to become 3. easiest would be to add this kind of constraint here.

Comment: Well, first - keys and state codes should be different. 2nd - you will not "stupidly" remove a state. Rather a migration program will run that first remaps states. In this case you do not need a cascading delete, not in reality.

Comment: I do not want a cascading delete. Cascading update would be finde enough like the rearranging part with read/accepted/solved/read. - If there would be a way to "fix" this, I can transfer it to a more complex database model I have. There I have a table where alot of data is deleted and created, so i get big gaps between IDs and i cant rearrange the data with lower IDs.